# What is meant by joint probability in a likelihood function for a geometric distribution?

Tags: likelihood

I have the following problem

> Consider a random variable Y that follows the distribution: 
> $P(Y=y|p) = (1-p)^y p $
>  where $y \in \{0,1,2,...\}$ 
> Imagine we observe a sample of n non-negative integers y =(y1,...., yn) and want to model them using the given distribution ( the data is independently and identically distributed). 
> Write
> down the likelihood function for the data y ( i.e the joint
> probability of the data under the given distribution with probability
> parameter p)

I am thrown by the word "joint" what would it be referring to, considering that we only have one random variable?

[Update]

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution) joint probability involves X and Y

Comment: I agree that is unclear phrasing.   I assume the question implies we have several observations of $y$, say $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n$, drawn independently from this distribution (with the same value for $p$), and the questioner wanted us to write down the joint distribution for the $y_i$, but only because I can't make sense of it any other way.

Comment: Oops, you are right thankyou. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, in your data, you have several random variables distributed identically and independently, i.e. $\mathcal D=\{Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n\}$ and the likelihood is defined as $$L(p|\mathcal D)=p(\mathcal D|p)=P(Y_1=y_1,Y_2=y_2,...,Y_n=y_n|p)=\prod_{i=1}^n P(Y_i=y_i|p)$$

Comment: Shouldn't the form of the distribution effect this answer? We are told the distribution is $(1-p)^ p$ but this is not mentioned in your answer.

Comment: It'll affect the final answer when you substitute for $P(Y_i=y_i|p)$, but the above form is always correct.

Comment: You already have the formula in the question statement. $(1-p)^{y_i}p$

Comment: So $(1-p)^{y_1}p ( 1-p)^{y_2} p ... etc$ ?

Comment: @KirstenGreed correct